# How would I finish this continuity proof?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I have a multivariable function $f$ with

$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x^2+y^2}{y} & \text{if }y \neq 0\\
0 & \text{if }y = 0
\end{cases}$$

and want to show that it is continuous at $(0, 0)$. In order to prove this, let there be two sequences $a_n$, $b_n$ with $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} b_n = 0$. Now consider:

$$\left|f(a_n, b_n) = \frac{a_n^2 + b_n^2}{b_n}\right| = \left|\frac{(a_n+b_n) + (a_n-b_n)}{b_n}\right| \leqslant \left|?\right| $$

As $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} b_n = 0$, we see by the squeeze theorem that for $n \to \infty :\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}f(a_n, b_n) = 0 = f(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n) = f(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n)$.

Thus, the function is continuous at $(0,0)$.

What could I use for $|?|$ in order to finish this proof?

**Edit:** It appears that my assumption was wrong, this function is not continuous at $(0, 0)$. For a counterexample, have a look into the answers.

Comment: It's not continuous at $(0, 0)$: Consider the path $x = y^{1/3}$.

Comment: @T.Bongers Could you elaborate on that? I'm not sure I understand the meaning of "path" here.

Comment: If we consider points of the form $(x, x^3)$ with $x$ very small, we have $$f(x, x^3) = \frac{x^2 + x^6}{x^3} = \frac 1 x + x^3$$ This becomes large as $x \to 0$, so the limit doesn't exist (as a real number). Note that there are points of this form arbitrarily close to zero.

Comment: I see. Chapeau! Just out of curiosity: Wouldn't this hold, using the same argument as you did, for general $(x, x^n), n \neq 1$, too? If you transfer your original answer into a comment, I'll mark this question solved.

Comment: Yes, it works for any pair $(x, x^n)$ with $n > 2$, since $f(x, x^n) = x^{2 - n} + x^{n}$; the first term is badly behaved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is not continuous at zero: Choose any sequence $a_n \to 0$ and $b_n = a_n^3$. Then we have

$$f(a_n, b_n) = f(a_n, a_n^3) = \frac{a_n^2 + a_n^6}{a_n^3} = \frac{1}{a_n}  + a_n^3$$

It follows that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(a_n, b_n)$ either doesn't exist, or is $\infty$, or is $-\infty$ (depending on how the signs of $a_n$ behave eventually). For the sake of definiteness, selecting $a_n = \frac 1 n$ gives

$$f(a_n, b_n) = n + \frac{1}{n^3} \to \infty$$

Answer (score 0):

$c\left|\dfrac{a_n}{b_n}\right|$, where $c\geq2$ is a possible candidate.

Comment: Except there's no reason to expect that $|a_n / b_n|$ remain bounded - in fact, choosing $b_n = a_n^3$ shows that this function is *not* continuous at $(0, 0)$.

Comment: @T.Bongers Yes, I agree with you. In fact, after I posted my answer, I saw your comment.